# Src de un iframe en php Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, iframe

buen dia!
Les cuento que estoy viendo un codigo en php que utilizo Symfony, al cual tengo que cambiar algunos estilos. 
En un formulario tiene un iframe con la siguiente src
     src="/web/index.php/formulario"

Tengo que cambiar el estilo de ese formulario pero no se en que parte del proyecto buscarlo. Evidentemente no hay una carpeta llamada index.php asi que calculo que esta cargando algo desde ahi.
Les paso el codigo de dicho index.php:

```
 <?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = 
 ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
 sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Desde ya mil gracias

Comment: Si tienes funcional el proyecto en symfony debes hacer php app/console debug:router Y ahí debería estar la llamada "formulario"

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de un proyecto realizado con symfony 1. En dicha versión, las rutas se almacenan dentro de cada aplicación (Un proyecto puede tener múltiples aplicaciones), en este caso la aplicación se llama **frontend** por eso debe buscar la ruta en: `apps/frontend/config/routing.yml`

En ese archivo encontrará la ruta deseada con la información del módulo que la administra. Por ejemplo puede encontrar algo similar a:

```
form_route:
  url:           /formulario
  param:         { module:myModule, action:myForm }
  requeriments:  { sf_method: post }
```

Esta ruta dice que debe ir al módulo **myModule** y buscar la acción **myForm** que debe estar en la ruta `apps/frontend/modules/myModule/actions/actions.class.php`. En ese archivo debe localizar el método llamado **executeMyForm** y en el podrá ver el código utilizado para renderizar el formulario.

Ya para ver la plantilla que maneja dicha acción debe ir a la ruta `apps/frontend/myModule/templates/myActionSuccess.php`